# Is there a way by which I can run 'aws configure command like "aws configure | access key | shared secret | region" '

Tags: node.js, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, cron-task

I'm making a crone job that switches cluster context every time and checks for stuff. But, for switching the context to EKS, I need to run `aws configure` every time to get logged in.

I'm wondering how this step can be fulfilled via a crone job that will also switch the context to EKS. If It is possible to run aws configure like AWS configure | key1 | key2 | region, I'll pass the input in via string templating.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to run `aws configure` every time to get logged in"? FYI, that command simply stores information in `~/.aws/credentials`, so you can always manipulate the content. Or, you might be able to specify a `--profile` when making an API call.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using EKS, I assume you are using aws-auth configmap also. To contact with EKS, you need to use a role or user inside aws-auth.

Here is what you can do now:

Make your credentials file having multiple profiles:

```
[profile1]
...
[profile2]
...
```

then you can switch profiles in your script by this environment variable:

```
export AWS_PROFILE=profile1
```

Example like:

```
export AWS_PROFILE=profile1
aws eks ...
kubectl ...

export AWS_PROFILE=profile2
aws eks ...
kubectl ...
```

The export part might be different in the real world, but the base script is similar.